# Expressjs - App posting to 404 loop

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-404

I have a node app running locally. Every 15 seconds, the console logs something that looks like this:

```
POST /api/98fca6685b31b88f4b2cd68e1c9be4f6 404 328.251 ms - 2075
```

The string after api/ is always the same (98fca6685b31b88f4b2cd68e1c9be4f6). I searched my app folder recursively for that string, which turned up nothing. Does anybody know what this is?

Comment: Is it coming from your browser or from someone else?

Comment: @mscdex That is being logged in my command line (terminal) when I start up the app locally. I don't know where it is coming from (generated in the app or a response from a module pinging a service?)

Comment: Can't say decisively, but thats a 32 char string - probably an MD5.

Comment: If you're unsure where the requests are coming from, you can use `morgan`'s [`short` predefined format](https://www.npmjs.org/package/morgan#predefined-formats) to add `:remote-addr` and `:remote-user` to what the `dev` format shows.